Use web API with implicit flow and client credentials flow
We have a .netCore web api protected by OAuth authentication for azureAD.
We use Microsoft.Identity.Web :
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, AzureAdOptions.Options, AzureAdOptions.BearerAuthenticationScheme);

It works perfectly with implicit flow, with a token that contain upn.
A customer want to call our api with client credentials flow and with it the token doesn't contain an user, only an appid.
We check id user is authenticated like this :
context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

But in this case User is null, that is normal.
I would like to add a function to validate the token and if this token doesn't have upn, set a mock user in context with appid as username.
Is there a mean to do that ?
Thank you for your help

When we have services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication and correct configurations, we've integrated Azure AD into our web api application, and after we adding [Authorize] attribute to controller or action, we have to add a correct access token into the request header to make sure to access the API.
For access tokens generated by Azure AD auth flows, there's mainly 2 kinds of tokens. One is generated by delegated API permissions which having scp claim and another is generated by application API permissions which having roles claim. And we shall validate them for difference scenarios. In our codes, it shall be [RequiredScope("scope_name")] or [Authorize(Roles = "required_role")]. More details can be seen in this official document, and my test sample is also based on this tutorial.
My program.cs has codes below, and I also test with builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration); which worked the same too.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));



You have a great idea that might require a custom middleware to get the access token ahead, then validate the token, if the token is valid but doesn't have upn, then setting a mock user in context. It will add extra work but if it's necessary, then we can do it.

Thank you for your help. We must mock user because all CRUD operations in API are historized with user login

@user1069516 Thanks for your confirmation. Then we have 2 approaches, one is using the authorization scheme like what I shared and create an extra middleware which only used to add the mock user after the validation. Another is create a custom middleware to cover the authorization too.. And certainly, we can create a method like createMockUserifUserNotExisted.
